# why python threadpool creat daemonic threads and join them at last?

Tags: python, threadpool, daemon

I've been reading python's threadpool module's [code](http://chrisarndt.de/projects/threadpool/threadpool.py.html).

It manipulates threads in this way : All workerThreads are created as daemonic thread. And it also have a dismiss mechanism that you can safely quit the worker thread by setting event, after all the job's done the dismissed threads will be joined in the main thread.

The [python doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects) says that if worker threads were set daemonic, they will quit when main thread terminates. But it might be an ugly implementation, a better way is to make them non-daemonic and stop them with event.

Here is my question: Is it a good design to use both of the quit strategies? Is it better to set the threads non-daemonic and join them all before the main thread terminates?

Comment: As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this question can be improved, see the [FAQ] for guidance on [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In looking at this particular threadpool module, it appears to be designed to work *either* by allowing you to quit summarily, *or* waiting for the threads to complete. You would choose one or the other depending on how you want to handle requests currently in process:

- If you don't care about whether threads die in the middle of processing requests, just let the program exit, and the daemon threads will be taken care of.
- On the other hand, if you want to make sure a thread exits only between fully processing requests, either use `dismissWorkers` with `do_join=True`, or use `dismissWorkers` followed by `joinAllDismissedWorkers`.

That choice would vary depending on what you're processing and how. Note that the sample code that comes in the main routine does some of one and some of the other, which is probably not what you'd want to do in a real situation – the sample code is just designed to demonstrate capabilities.

You could argue that it's bad form to create daemon threads when you *do* care about how/when they exit, and it wouldn't be hard to fix the library so that daemon is an option for your worker threads when they are created, not a necessity. Currently, however, the module picks a default that favors ease of use over consistency.